# How to write this nifty way?rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to write this code in more elegant way in my view.
Can you help me?

```
<%= if category.photo.present?
    category.photo
    else 
    category.img_parse_url
end %>
```

`category.photo` might be nil or empty string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [try](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) method which is not needed here as @tadman pointed out, besides, as you wrote below in comment `photo` can be an empty string (I wrongly assumed it cannot be) so those two versions will return an empty string if `category.photo` is just an empty string:

`<= category.try(:photo) || category.img_parse_url %>`

And without `try`:

`<= category.photo || category.img_parse_url %>`

or move that to model.

edit:

If the photo can be an empty string then maybe use ternary operator?

`<%= category.photo.present? ? category.photo : category.img_parse_url %>`

or use the [presence](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/presence) method:

`<%= category.photo.presence || category.img_parse_url %>`

Comment: `try` isn't necessary here. That method exists.

Comment: So will this work if `category.photo` is empty string? ( if it is empty string I should also display `img_parse_url`

Comment: Can you also include the  answer with try method for the complete reference for me for the future!?

Comment: @user2950593: added it above.